interpreting nsight compute output for coarsened kernels
I have been trying to understand effects of thread coarsening (also known as thread merge or 1xN tiling) on convolution operation. In that case, my focus was reducing the memory access instructions for overlapping elements and reuse the convolution matrix elements for neighbor threads. In experience, I have seen the results that prove global memory load instructions (LDG) extremely reduced with the increase of coarsening factor. In the other hand, strided accesses led increase at the requested sectors which means more uncoalesced memory accesses. As shown in table at the below.



Coarsening Factor
Execution Time (ns)
LDG
Req/Sector




2
648
5.5M
2.14


4
492
3.5M
3.44


8
406
2.5M
6.68


12
562
2.3M
9.98


16
733
2.0M
14.02



But I do not understand "Why transition from 8x to 12x slows down the performance". I have been using Nsight Compute to analyse the kernel behavior, there is memory chart tables for 8x coarsening and 12x coarsening versions and their comparision.
Memory Tables for 8x Coarsened Kernel:

Memory Tables for 12x Coarsened Kernel:

Also there is complete code snippet for kernels I use in this post: https://godbolt.org/z/dcz1cs354
Since I am not familiar with Nsight Compute and its metrics. I do not know where should i take a look or how should i interpret that kind of situation.

Please include a minimal, reproducible example. It's rather unhelpful if we have to guess what exactly you did

For your request, I have added compiler explorer outcome at the end of the post @Homer512. Thanks for notifying..

I do not understand why this post is receiving "downvote". I have shared as much as information I can share and asked my question explicitly. If I had a chance upload the Nsight Compute report I would do that too.

While Compiler Explorer is a great tool, links break (especially the shortened ones like the one you used) and are therefore not an acceptable way of providing critical information on SO. SO Q&As are supposed to help/provide information to future readers. The question author being helped is more of a nice side effect. That is why these kinds of rules are taken so seriously. (FYI I'm not a down-voter of your question.)

Linking to godbolt as an addition to an MRE is nice to have. But the question should be reasonably self-contained. Plus, the amount of code you linked seems excessive for what you are asking. There are two kernels of interest here plus enough of a main to execute it for the profiler. That should be the MRE
